# difference between DBREINDEX and INDEXDEFRAG

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know difference between DBCC DBREINDEX and DBCC INDEXDEFRAG and when we will go with reindex , when we will go with defradmentation of index?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or greater you should be thinking in terms of `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` or `ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE` instead of the two commands you are asking about. You can look them up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx).

Same difference applies though essentially, though the locking of the tables has changed as well if you are on enterprise as you can perform these operations in online mode allowing users to access the tables while you do the work.

Rebuild is closest to DBReindex, Reorganize is closest to Indexdefrag.

Comment: Is difference between rebuild and reorganise same to DBReindex and IndexDefrag.

Comment: essentially yes, but again if you aren't on SQL Server 2000 or below you should be using the new syntax. That books online article I sent you in my answer explains this more.

Answer (score 1):

- DBREINDEX = rebuild a copy of the index(es) from scratch
- INDEXDEFRAG = defragments page by page

DBREINDEX will always defragment as clean copies are made whereas INDEXDEFRAG churns pages

Both are deprecated in favour of [ALTER INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) where

- DBREINDEX  = REBUILD option "Rebuilding Indexes" +in this link
- INDEXDEFRAG = REORGANISE option = "Reorganizing Indexes" in this link